# Twitter Bot with Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, bots

This is the error it gives me:

You currently have access to Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve

Does anyone know if I have to pay the Premium Twitter Developer for the bot to post a tweet?

I'm trying to make a bot post 3 tweets a day and I was expecting it to work.

Comment: Are you using the Tweepy v1 or v2 API?

Comment: I’m not sure. I think I’m using v2. How do I check? Thanks for helping!

Comment: Do you call `tweepy.API()` v1 or `tweepy.Client()` v2?

Comment: tweepy.API, so its v1. Do I change it to Client()?

Comment: I would try that yes.

Comment: Can you help me code the bot? I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. Or can you recommend somewhere to learn how to do it? Thanks JonSG

Answer (score 1):

this is how it worked for me:

```
import tweepy


# # # Authenticate to Twitter
CONSUMER_KEY = 'your consumer key'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'your consumer secret'
ACCESS_TOKEN = 'your access token'
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = 'your access token secret'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(API_KEY, API_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)

# # Create API object
client = tweepy.Client(consumer_key=API_KEY, consumer_secret=API_SECRET, access_token=ACCESS_KEY, access_token_secret=ACCESS_SECRET)

# # Create a tweet
client.create_tweet(text='this is fine')
```